# How to make AutoMapper create an instance of class

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have the following source type:

```
public class Source
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following destination types:

```
public class Destination
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Address HomeAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

I created a mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
```

How do I configure my mapping so it will create an instance of Address and map the Address.PostalCode property using the Source property ZipCode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With AfterMap, you can specify how to map entities further after AutoMapper has done it's mapping.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
                .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                              {
                                  dest.HomeAddress = new Address {PostalCode = src.ZipCode};
                              }
            );
```

Comment: I tried this. Does not work. Expression 'dest => Convert(dest.Address.PostalCode)' must resolve to top-level member.

Comment: Also, I don't want to put the initialization in my constructor because I don't want to always create and Address when I instantiate a new Destination, only when I map from a Source do I want an Address created.

Comment: @Dismissile, It's failing because you are resolving to `Convert(...)` not `dest.Address.PostalCode`. Also, looking at the examples here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection it looks like you might not need to include the empty constructor, as long as both classes do have default constructors.

Comment: Ok then how do I get it to not resolve to Convert(...). I typed in exactly like you have it and I get the error.

Comment: @Dismissle, I screwed up. You do have to use the top level properties with MapFrom, but you can use an AfterMap. I updated my post.

Comment: can we use automapper for C# 2.0 version ?